# How to select data in Partition of more than 1 month

Tags: sql, oracle

I need another Query to get some data using Partitions, actually I use this but it takes to much time

```
select * FROM XPTO WHERE    
START_DATE between to_date('2017-07-01 00:00:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2017-10-31 23:59:59','yyyy-mm-dd  hh24:mi:ss')
```

Regars

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.

Comment: `select FROM XPTO` -- Column names are missing. If you want everthing use `select * FROM XPTO`

Comment: Yeah of course its select * from XPTO

Comment: How is the table partitioned? You can either use the partition key in the `where` clause, or else specify the partition name explicitly.

Comment: My Table is partitioned by DATE (MONTH).like P201701, P201702,P201703, etc